# dotnet tool available globally but can't run command

Tags: .net

Running dotnet v7

```
dotnet --version
# => 7.0.100
```

I installed dotnet-warp using the command

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-warp
```

I am able to run `dotnet tool list -g` with the following result

| Package Id | Version | Commands |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dotnet-warp | 1.1.0 | dotnet-warp |

However, when I run `dotnet-warp --version` I get the following error

> zsh: command not found: dotnet-warp

Our team is not proficient in .NET, but we occasionally have to maintain this legacy project so I hope there is something I am missing here.

Expected to execute command after verifying it was installed in the global tool list.

Comment: Did you include the tool directory in your path?

Comment: Also that tool is long deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Needed to add the tool to my path!